# Как раньше называлась капуста?

Tags: этимология

Может быть, вопрос глупый, но мне подумалось: слово "капуста" латинского происхождения и происходит от слова "голова". Но латинский в русский язык проник гораздо позже того, как этот традиционно русский овощ стали повсеместно сажать.
А есть ли какое-то русское название у капусты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приблизительно в X или XI в. на Руси появилась капуста. Примерно тогда же входит употребление русск.-церк.-слав. капуста (1193 г., 1195). Вероятно, раньше ни овощ ни название не встречались у славян.

Comment: Возникает  вопрос:  из  какого  района   проникает  на  Русь  капуста  вместе  с  названием ?  Латинский  у  неё  только  "кап"  в  корне.